# Not working udev rule with systemd-udevd on Fedora 19

Tags: linux, fedora, udev, systemd

I would like to play with [IOIO](https://github.com/ytai/ioio/wiki) on my Fedora 19, so I installed the [udev rule](https://github.com/ytai/ioio/wiki/Using-IOIO-With-a-PC#connecting-the-ioio-as-a-serial-port) as the documentation tells, in `/etc/udev/rules.d/50-ioio.rules`:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1b4f", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0008", SYMLINK+="IOIO%n", MODE="666"
```

This should create some `/dev/IOIO**` devices after restarting the service. But it does not work for me.

Since Fedora 18, udev has been replaced by systemd-udevd, could it be related ? Is this rule correctly written for Fedora 19 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to set only one subsystem

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1b4f", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0008", SYMLINK+="IOIO%n", MODE="666"
```